# Can I use the grand canonical ensemble for a photon gas?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, photons

I have been reading about photon gases at https://www2.chem.utah.edu/steele/doc/chem7040/chandlerch4.pdf. They do the analysis using a canonical ensemble.
Since photon numbers are not conserved, I would have thought it would be more appropriate to use the grand canonical ensemble. Would it be wrong to do so?

Comment: It's precisely because photons have no mass (i.e. no energy cost to create a zero kinetic energy photon, i.e. number not conserved) that you *don't* need the grand canonical ensemble!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grand canonical ensemble allows the number of particles of your system to fluctuate but makes the assumption that it is constant amongst the reservoir and system combined i.e.

$$
n_{res} + n_{sys} = const
$$

For the case of photons this is not true.

Comment: Once you set the chemical potential to zero for a photon gas, this condition of conserving the number of particles is resolved.

Comment: dont we have the assumption of fixed particle number in system in canonical ensemble??